# Can I use a different dilimter other than EOF or EOL when reading a file

Tags: java

I want to parse a file and use 2 'new line' (\n) as a dilimiter instead of EOL and add that into a string object.

Here is the algorithm -

```
1. While end of file is not reached
2. Read a file until you hit 2 \n's or eof is reached
  put that contents as a string to a List object. 
3. go to 1.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Scanner.useDelimiter()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#delimiter%28%29) method.

```
public Scanner useDelimiter(String pattern)
```

> Sets this scanner's delimiting pattern to a pattern constructed from
>   the specified String.

[According to JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.4) new line is

> LineTerminator:
>
> ```
> the ASCII LF character, also known as "newline"
>
> the ASCII CR character, also known as "return"
>
> the ASCII CR character followed by the ASCII LF character
> ```

Answer (score 1):

You can use any delimiter you want.  If you [use Scanner you can set the delimiter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#delimiter%28%29).

Note: a new line is usually `(\r\n|\r|\n)` to support three variations of a new line.

In your case the simplest solution may be to do

```
String[] paragraphs = FileUtils.readFileAsString(filename)
                               .split("(\r\n|\r|\n){2}");
```